# Variable no Visible

Tags: java, variables

Que tal amigos estoy trabajando en Java y estoy utilizando el IDE Eclipse version 4.10.0

Me he econtrado con un error de visibilidad de una varible, pero no he econtrado la solucion. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
package com.clases;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Juego {

public static void main(String argumentos[]) {
    /*
     * Al inicio del juego se llenan las armas basicas. 
     */
    Arma.llenarArmasBasicas(); 
    //llenamos las secciones de los escenarios
    Esenario.llenarEscenariosPredefiidos();
    System.out.println("Bienvenido al juego");
    if(argumentos.length>0) {
        Juego juego=new Juego(argumentos[0],Esenario.esenariosDisponibles);
    }else {
        Juego juego = new Juego(pedirNombre(),Esenario.esenariosDisponibles);
    }       
}
}
```

El Constructor de la clase Juego es el siguiente

```
public Juego(String nombre,Esenario[] eseanrios) {
    Jugador jugador = new Jugador(nombre);
    this.jugadorPrincipal=jugador;
    esenarios=eseanrios;
}
```

Y el metodo pedirNombre es:

```
public static String pedirNombre() {
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del jugador");
    return lector.next();
}
```

El error me dice que la variable 'argumentos' del metodo principal no es visible y al correrlo me lanza la siguente excepcion:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The type String is not visible

at com.clases.Juego.main(Juego.java:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que te funcione correctamente debes corregir el tipo de dato de argumentos del método main

*La manera correcta es

```
public static void main(String[] argumentos) {
    //Codigo
}
```

Lo estás declarando String argumentos[].

Saludos

Comment: Ya lo he intentado asi, Pero sigue sin funcionar. Gracias amigo!

Answer (score 0):

Ya econtre mi propia solucion así que la dejaré por aca para que alguien más la vea y talvez le sirva.

El problema es que Eclipse 4.10 tiene cietos errores con el JDK 11. 
Así que la solción es:

Cambiar el JDK a uno anterior, por ejemplo el JDK 8 ó,

Acutalizar Eclipse a su version 4.11. (Lo cual no me aparece aún en los repositorios de AUR)